# Does logn grow faster than n^0.3

Tags: big-o

Which one grows faster and why?
O(logn) or O(n^0.3)

I tried it with some values of n and it seems that O(n^0.3) grows faster. The whole class says logn grows faster but I'm not convinced. It would be great if I can have some sort of a proof.

Comment: `O(logn)` - binary search **|** `O(n^0.3)` - bogo search?

Answer (score 1):

O(log N) grows slower than N to any positive power.

L'Hôpital's rule of N^x/log(N) results in xN^(x - 1) / N^-1 = xN^(x - 1) * N

Therefore the limit is +∞ and N^x grows asymptotically faster than log(N) for all x > 0.